# How to fulfill the kernel modules dependencies?

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm building my own kernel enabling some modules which aren't enabled by default. For my dismay, I found out that even if I use `script/config -m module` to enable the module, this doesn't assures me that the dependencies will be satisfied, such that when `make oldconfig` runs to prepare the kernel, my option will be left undefined!

This forces me to go one by one on all dependencies, just to build a single module. Is there a way that would automagically fulfill the configuration dependencies for me?

Case point: AXP288_FUEL_GAUGE configuration option. (I'm using 4.11 as reference, but I've seen this same behavior on previous kernels)

According to LKDDb it depends on [CONFIG_MFD_AXP20X](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/AXP288_FUEL_GAUGE.html). Until I enable the later, AXP288_FUEL_GAUGE wouldn't appear at all under the power devices list.

Comment: How are you enabling modules? How do you know dependencies aren't satisfied?

Comment: @MichaelMol it's on the post: `script/config -m module`

Comment: Are you looking for a trivially-scriptable approach, or is interactive OK?

Comment: @MichaelMol preferable if it's included with the kernel scripts/tools.